# travelling before schengen visa expires

Tags: schengen

I have a Schengen visa from French embassy valid between 25-05 to 10-06-2019 for the stay of 15 days.

I want to travel on 6th June for 10 days. That is 6th June to 16th June, is it ok or do I have to travel between 25-05 to 10-06-2019. Please advise.

Comment: 6 May was two and a half weeks ago.  Are you sure the dates in this question are correct?

Comment: oops sorry 6th june to 16th june i meant.

Comment: Note that if someone enters the Schengen area on June 6 and leaves on June 16, that counts as 11 days of presence in the Schengen area, even though the duration of such a visit could be anywhere from just over 216 hours to just under 264 hours.

Answer (score 4):

You may not be present in the Schengen area before the "from" date of your visa nor after its "to" date.  I assume that you actually meant to ask about a trip from 6 to 16 June, since the period from 6 to 16 May is in the recent past.

If you enter on 6 June, or on any day between 27 May and 10 June, you will have to leave the Schengen area on or before 10 June.  So the answer to your question is *no,* it is not okay, and *yes,* you have to travel between 25-05 to 10-06-2019.

Comment: @phoog your advice is always good and to the point. thanks to help me also i will get back with answer of my question soon.

Comment: @user97980 you can of course apply for a new visa, in theory, but there may not be enough time.